# Grouped custom taxonomy query

Tags: customization, taxonomy

I have created

- 1 custom post types: image-gallery
- 1 custom taxonomy: media-category
- 2 categories (under Media Categories): categoria-uno and
  categoria-due

I need to print the records grouped by category, example:

Categoria uno

- record 1
- record 2
- record 3

Categoria due

- record 1
- record 2
- record 3

Anybody could please help me with this query?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need nested queries, first you should think about, which data is needed. In your example you need all terms of a tanonomy as well as all posts belonging to each taxonomy. So the first step should be to find a way to loop through all terms of a taxonomy:

```
    /* TAXONOMIES  */
    // args
    $args_tax = array(
        'order' => ASC);
    // get terms
    $terms = get_terms($tax, $args_tax);
    $count = count($terms);
    if ($count > 0) {
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            echo "<li>";
            echo $term->name;
            echo "</li>";
            }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

In the next step you have to loop through the posts:

```
    /* CPT POSTS  */
    // args
    $args_cpt = array(
            'post_type' => $cpt,
            'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => $tax,
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $term->slug
                    )
             )
     );
    // get posts
    $tax_query = new WP_Query($args_cpt);
    if ($tax_query->have_posts()) {
            echo "<ul>";
            while ($tax_query->have_posts()) {
                    $tax_query->the_post();
                    echo "<li>";
                    echo get_the_title();
                    echo "</li>";
                    }                    
            echo "</ul>";
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Now you have to combine the two loops. For example in a function placed in functions.php:

```
/**
 * RFRQ
 * the_posts_by_tax
 */

if (!function_exists('the_posts_by_tax')) {
    function the_posts_by_tax($cpt, $tax) {
        /* TAXONOMIES  */
        // args
        $args_tax = array(
            'order' => ASC);
        // get terms
        $terms = get_terms($tax, $args_tax);
        $count = count($terms);
        if ($count > 0) {
            echo "<ul>";
            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                echo "<li>";
                echo $term->name;                
                /* CPT POSTS  */
                // args
                $args_cpt = array(
                    'post_type' => $cpt,
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => $tax,
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => $term->slug
                        )
                    )
                );
                // get posts
                $tax_query = new WP_Query($args_cpt);
                if ($tax_query->have_posts()) {
                    echo "<ul>";
                    while ($tax_query->have_posts()) {
                        $tax_query->the_post();
                        echo "<li>";
                        echo get_the_title();
                        echo "</li>";
                    }                    
                    echo "</ul>";
                }
                wp_reset_postdata();
                echo "</li>";
            }
            echo "</ul>";
        }
    }
}
```

You can call your loop through:

```
the_posts_by_tax($cpt, $tax)
```

Comment: You should mark my answer as accepted to show other users that they can expect a working solution.